# My question is about recurrence of numbers and sequences in C++ and how to print them?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, math, recurrence

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i;
    const int N = 5;
    for (i = 1; i <= N; i++){
        double Yn = (1.0 / 2) * (Yn - 1) +  (1.0 / 3) * (Yn - 2);
        std::cout << i << " " << "= "<< " " << Yn;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have an equation and a table of sequences.

**Equation**

```
Y[n] = 1/2*(Y[n-1]) + 1/3*(Y[n-2])

Y[1] = 0.5, Y[2] = 0.4
```

The table shown below should be printed by using for loops.

```
N -- Yn  
1 -- 0.5  
2 -- 0.4  
3 -- 0.366667  
4 -- 0.316667  
5 -- 0.280556
```

All I have to do is to print the above table .

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: What is your question exactly?
Also, you redefine `double Yn` on every loop iteration using itself (i.e. you create new Yn for each loop iteration, you don't recomnpute it based on previous values). Seems like it should be declared outside the loop first.

Comment: Edited the question with the table and equation

Comment: please check my edit and roll back if it is not ok. I dont know how to write subscripts , but imho not its less wrong/confusing than before

Comment: But the table still don't match.

Answer (score 4):

You wrote down the sequence wrong.

You have:

> Yn = 1/2*(Yn - 1) + 1/3*(Yn - 2)

But it should be:

> Y<sub>n</sub> = 1/2*(Y<sub>n-1</sub>) + 1/3*(Y<sub>n-2</sub>)

So you need to keep track of the previous two numbers in the sequence to calculate the next one:

```
int i=1;
const int N = 5;
double Y_prev1 = 0.4;
double Y_prev2 = 0.5;
std::cout << i++ << " " << "= "<< " " << Y_prev2 << std::endl;
std::cout << i++ << " " << "= "<< " " << Y_prev1 << std::endl;
for (; i <= N; i++){
    double Y = (1.0 / 2) * (Y_prev1) +  (1.0 / 3) * (Y_prev2);
    std::cout << i << " " << "= "<< " " << Y;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    Y_prev2 = Y_prev1;
    Y_prev1 = Y;
}
```

Output:

```
1 =  0.5
2 =  0.4
3 =  0.366667
4 =  0.316667
5 =  0.280556
```

Comment: `double Y[N];` might also make sense. with a notation near of given equation.

Comment: `Y_prev2 = Y_prev1;
    Y_prev1 = Y;` Can yo tell me what is this for ?

Comment: To calculate each number in the sequence, you need the prior two numbers.  After each iteration of the loop, you need to update what the last two numbers were.  Those two statements do that.

Comment: @user83869 So at the end of each iteration, `Y` becomes `Y_prev1`, and `Y_prev1` becomes `Y_prev2`.